Square Brackets around paragraph text!
thank you for solving my last problem Re. Headers. I have another question Re. the use of square brackets around paragraph of text. Though I fear the solution won't be as easy this time. I've again included my MWE and the style code which I fear maybe interfering with the output.

\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=1.2cm,right=1.2cm,headheight=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{psalm}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{bold-extra}
\graphicspath{ {C:/Users/culle/Documents/Scores/Magnificat Chants} }

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancyhead{} % clear all header fields
\fancyhead[R]{\bfseries\scshape Day 1}
\fancyhead[L]{\bfseries\scshape Morning Prayer}

\begin{center}
    {\Large \textbf{Psalm 1}}\\
    \textit{Beatus vir, qui non abiit.}
    \begin{flushright}
        William Beale (1784--1854)\\
    \end{flushright}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.99]{Beale in A Minor.png}
\end{center}

% override width of verse text because these lines are quite short
\setlength\textamount{14cm}

\begin{center}
\begin{psalm} % override number of first verse (optional)
    
\vs{\quad\dyn{mp}}{\textbf{Bl\syl{e}ss\syl{e}d is the man that hath not walked in the counsel of the ungodly, * \breaklongline 
    nor stood in the | way of | sinners}}
{}{\textbf{and hath not | sat_in the | seat_of the | scornful.}}

\vs{\quad\dyn{mf}}{\textbf{But his delight is in the | law_of the | Lord}}
{}{\textbf{and in his law will he | exer_cise him | self_day and | night.}}\\


\vs{\quad\dyn{p}}{And he shall be like a tree planted | by the | water-side}
{}{that will bring forth his | fruit in | due | season.}

\vs{\quad\dyn{mp}}{His leaf also | shall not | wither}
{}{and look, * whatsoever he | d\syl{o}\syl{e}th, | it shall | prosper.}\\


\vs{\quad\dyn{f}}{As for the ungodly, it is not | so with | them}
{}{but they are like the chaff, * \breaklongline
     which the wind scattereth a | way_from the | face of_the | earth.\vspace{0.7em}}

\vs{\quad}{Therefore the ungodly shall not be able to | stand_in the | judgement}
{}{neither the sinners in the congre | gation | of the | righteous.}\\


\vs{\second}{\textbf{But the Lord knoweth the | way_of the | righteous}}
{}{\textbf{and the | way of_the un | godly_shall | perish.}}

\stanzagap

        \vsnonums{\quad}{\textbf{Glory | be_to the | Father,}}
        {}{\textbf{and to the Son | and_to the | Holy | Ghost;}}

        \vsnonums{\quad}{\textbf{As it was in the beginning, is now, and | ever | shall be}}
        {}{\textbf{world without | end. A | - - | men}}

\end{psalm}
\end{center}

\usepackage{array}



% HORIZONTAL SPACING

\setlength\parindent{0pt}

% amount of space for notes e.g. dynamics and Full
\newlength\notesamount
\setlength\notesamount{4.5em}

% amount of space for verse numbers
\newlength\versenumamount
\setlength\versenumamount{1.5em}

% amount of space for verse text
\newlength\textamount
\setlength\textamount{20cm}

% amount to indent second half of each verse
\newlength\indentamount
\setlength\indentamount{1em}



% VERTICAL SPACING

% vertical space between verses
\newlength\versesepamount
\setlength\versesepamount{0.7em}

% vertical space between sections of psalm
\newlength\stanzagapamount
\setlength\stanzagapamount{1.2em}



% define right-aligned paragraph column for use below
\newcolumntype{R}[1]
    {>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}

% verse number
\newcounter{VerseCounter}

% environment for psalm text
\newenvironment{psalm}[1][1]
{
    % number of first verse
    \setcounter{VerseCounter}{#1}
    \begin{tabular}{ R{\notesamount} R{\versenumamount} p{\textamount} }
}
{
    \end{tabular}
}



% below we set some characters as 'active' characters,
% allowing them to be defined as macros

% bar line
\catcode`|=\active
\newcommand{|}{\textbar}

% dot for change of note (use instead of space between words)
\catcode`_=\active
\newcommand{_}
    {\hspace{0.15em}$\vcenter{\hbox{\tiny$\bullet$}}$\hspace{0.15em}}

% pause between words
\newcommand{\ps}
    {*\space}

% dynamics style
\newcommand{\dyn}[1]{\textbf{\textit{#1}}}

% second half of chant
\newcommand{\second}{$\dagger$}

% dot above letter to denote syllable
\newcommand{\syl}[1]{$\dot{\textrm{#1}}$}



% verses use the following columns:
% dynamics and full markings | verse numbers | verse text

% normal verse
\newcommand{\vs}[4]{#1 & \theVerseCounter.\stepcounter{VerseCounter} &
    #2\thinspace :\\
    #3 & &\hspace{\indentamount}#4\\[\versesepamount]}

% verse without gap in middle
\newcommand{\vscontinue}[4]{#1 & \theVerseCounter.\stepcounter{VerseCounter} &
    #2\thinspace : \raisebox{-0.08em}{\large{$\longrightarrow$}}\\
    #3 & &\hspace{\indentamount}#4\\[\versesepamount]}

% verse without verse number e.g. Gloria
\newcommand{\vsnonums}[4]{#1 & & #2\thinspace :\\
    #3 & &\hspace{\indentamount}#4\\[\versesepamount]}

% break a long line and indent appropriately
\newcommand{\breaklongline}{\newline\hbox{}\hspace{2\indentamount}}

% gap to signify a new section of the psalm
\newcommand{\stanzagap}{\vspace{\stanzagapamount}\\[-12pt]}

